# SQL Server - complete results with non existent data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where I have all the customers and a table where I have all their restrictions.

```
CUSTOMER

customer_id customer_name
1 name 1
2 name 2

CUSTOMER_RESTRICTIONS

rest_type day_of_week hour_start hour_stop customer_id

TYPE1  0  08:00  12:00  1
TYPE1  0  13:00  17:00  1
TYPE2  0  17:00  23:59  1
```

Problem: I only have a record for a restriction type and a customer when the customer has a restriction and this is a problem in the visualization I want to build.

I need every customer, every day and every restriction type, even when there is no restriction. In that case hour_start and hour_stop would be NULL.

For the tables shown, the output would be

```
rest_type day_of_week hour_start hour_stop customer_id

TYPE1  0  08:00  12:00  1
TYPE1  0  08:00  12:00  1
TYPE1  1  NULL  NULL  1
TYPE1  2  NULL  NULL  1
TYPE1  3  NULL  NULL  1
TYPE1  4  NULL  NULL  1
TYPE1  5  NULL  NULL  1
TYPE1  6  NULL  NULL  1
TYPE1  1  NULL  NULL  1
TYPE1  2  NULL  NULL  1
TYPE1  3  NULL  NULL  1
TYPE1  4  NULL  NULL  1
TYPE1  5  NULL  NULL  1
TYPE2  0  NULL  NULL  1
TYPE2  1  NULL  NULL  1
TYPE2  2  NULL  NULL  1
TYPE2  3  NULL  NULL  1
TYPE2  4  NULL  NULL  1
TYPE2  5  NULL  NULL  1
TYPE2  6  NULL  NULL  1
TYPE1  0  NULL  NULL  2
TYPE1  1  NULL  NULL  2
TYPE1  2  NULL  NULL  2
TYPE1  3  NULL  NULL  2
TYPE1  4  NULL  NULL  2
TYPE1  5  NULL  NULL  2
TYPE1  6  NULL  NULL  2
TYPE2  0  NULL  NULL  2
TYPE2  1  NULL  NULL  2
TYPE2  2  NULL  NULL  2
TYPE2  3  NULL  NULL  2
TYPE2  4  NULL  NULL  2
TYPE2  5  NULL  NULL  2
TYPE2  6  NULL  NULL  2
```

How can I achieve that? I couldn't even start to build this query.

Comment: Can we assume that you have a customer table as well where your customer_id's are stored?

Comment: I can't understand what you want to do there, could you please post a desired results? it would be great.

Comment: Also I don't see `day_of_week 1` there, your question is not clear, please [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53418263/edit)

Comment: I'll update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you need to start with the data you must have and left join the optional data. E.g., something like this:

```
select c.customer_id
    ,r.[rest_type]
    ,d.[day_of_week]
    ,r.[hour_start]
    ,r.[hour_stop]
from CUSTOMER c
cross apply (
    select 0 as day_of_week
    union all select 1
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
    union all select 4
    union all select 5
    union all select 6
) d 
left join CUSTOMER_RESTRICTIONS r on c.customer_id = r.customer_id and d.day_of_week = r.day_of_week
```

Output:

```
customer_id rest_type day_of_week hour_start hour_stop
----------- --------- ----------- ---------- ---------
1           TYPE1     0           08:00      12:00
1           TYPE1     0           13:00      17:00
1           TYPE2     0           17:00      23:59
1           NULL      1           NULL       NULL
1           NULL      2           NULL       NULL
1           NULL      3           NULL       NULL
1           NULL      4           NULL       NULL
1           NULL      5           NULL       NULL
1           NULL      6           NULL       NULL
```

If there are only type rest_types, you don't have a lookup table for them, and you want to show a row for each, you would do:

```
select c.customer_id
    ,t.[rest_type]
    ,d.[day_of_week]
    ,r.[hour_start]
    ,r.[hour_stop]
from CUSTOMER c
cross apply (
    select 0 as day_of_week
    union all select 1
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
    union all select 4
    union all select 5
    union all select 6
) d 
cross apply (
    select 'TYPE1' as rest_type
    union all select 'TYPE2'
) t
left join CUSTOMER_RESTRICTIONS r on c.customer_id = r.customer_id 
    and d.day_of_week = r.day_of_week 
    and t.rest_type = r.rest_type
```

Comment: Only The Beatles have 8 days a week :)

Comment: @DaveCullum I had to allow for 0 representing no data, since no other values were present initially.

Answer (score 0):

```
  (select rest_type, day_of_week,
   hour_start ,
   hour_stop 
   from table A
   where rest_type IS NOT NULL)
   Union
   (select rest_type, 
    day_of_week, 
    NULL ,NULL
    from table A 
     where rest_type IS NULL)
```

> Is this what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I wouldn't store rest type as you are, that is a bad habit, it should be a reference table!

You need to cross apply to get all your possible combinations, and then add in the values you DO have...

```
DECLARE @Customer TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Name NVARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @Rest TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Name NVARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @Restrictions TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), RestID INT, CustomerID INT, Day_of_Week TINYINT, hour_start TIME, hour_end TIME)

INSERT INTO @Customer (NAME)
VALUES('JOHN'),('SUSAN')

INSERT INTO @Rest (NAME)
VALUES ('TYPE A'),('TYPE B')

INSERT INTO @Restrictions (RestID,CustomerID,Day_of_Week,hour_start,hour_end)
VALUES (1,1,0,'08:00','12:00'),
       (1,1,0,'13:00','17:00'),
       (1,2,0,'17:00','23:59')

;WITH DaysofWeek AS
(
    SELECT 0 AS dow
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dow+1
    FROM DaysofWeek
    WHERE dow<5
)

SELECT *
FROM @Customer C
CROSS APPLY @Rest R
CROSS APPLY DaysofWeek D
LEFT JOIN @Restrictions X
   ON X.Day_of_Week=D.dow
   AND X.CustomerID=C.Id
   AND X.RestID=R.Id
ORDER BY C.Id, D.dow, R.Id
```